# Passing text from a file into a webview via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview

I'm attempting to pass the contents of a file into a Webview. Using the debugger I know that fileContents correctly contains the contents of the file, and that the file is read correctly. However, I'm getting a JavaScript 'EOF' error within the webview. Does the text need to be escaped or encoded before I pass it into the webview? Could newline characters within fileContents be disrupting stringByEvaluatingJava...?

```
//get file contents
NSStringEncoding *encoding;
NSError *error;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path usedEncoding:encoding error:&error];

//trigger fileopen event and pass file contents into webview
NSString *event = @"fileopen";
NSString *extraJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"e.results='%@'",fileContents];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var e = document.createEvent('Events'); e.initEvent('%@', true, false); %@; document.dispatchEvent(e); ", event, extraJS];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
```

Edit (based on Hezi's response):

```
NSString * result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"e.result=decodeURIComponent('%@')",[results stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[JSEventHelper triggerEvent:@"load" withExtraJS:result forWebView:self.webView];
```

Seems very weird that the above works, but it does!

Comment: The reason it wasn't working before is that `fileContents` contains at least one apostrophe. It's the same basic problem as an SQL injection vulnerability: The string you spliced in contained a character that ended the string, so everything after that gets treated as code. Encoding on the Cocoa side and decoding on the JS side solves that by hiding the apostrophe—and, hopefully, all other JS-special characters—from the JS interpreter.

Comment: By the way, your usage of `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:` is wrong. You must pass a pointer to storage for an `NSStringEncoding`. You are currently passing a garbage pointer (or `NULL` if you're using ARC, but passing `NULL` isn't guaranteed to work with this method). The fix is to declare `encoding` as holding an `NSStringEncoding`, not a pointer to one, and pass the pointer to the variable to `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using NSString's method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to encode your string before sending it to javascript.

Comment: Additionally, if there are newline characters in the JS string, the command might also fail. This can be fixed with **stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]**